# Nonsense error message when manually calling EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, timer, event-handling, eventhandler

If I have an EventHandler with the following signature:

```
public static void ProcessStuff(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

And If I attempt to manually call the EventHandler like so:

```
ProcessStuff(this, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs.Empty);
```

Why Do I get the error message:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from `'System.EventArgs'` to
>   `'System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs'`

**EDIT:** I also get the same error message If I set the manual call as:

```
ProcessStuff(this, System.EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/timers/system/timers/ElapsedEventArgs.cs,fa59a445f56b7851 `ElapsedEventArgs` doesn't redeclare `Empty` and that's why `System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs.Empty` is of type `System.EventArgs`

Comment: How bloody stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have a look at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/timers/system/timers/ElapsedEventArgs.cs,fa59a445f56b7851

we'll see that `System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs` *doesn't redeclare* `Empty`:

```
// No "Empty" (re-)declaration here
public class ElapsedEventArgs : EventArgs {   
    private DateTime signalTime;

    internal ElapsedEventArgs(int low, int high) {        
        long fileTime = (long)((((ulong)high) << 32) | (((ulong)low) & 0xffffffff));
        this.signalTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(fileTime);                        
    }

    public DateTime SignalTime {
        get {
            return this.signalTime;
        }
    }
}
```

and that's why when we call `System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs.Empty` we actually call `System.EventArgs.Empty` which is of type `System.EventArgs`:

```
Console.Write(System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs.Empty.GetType().Name);
```

Finally, there's no *implicit cast* from `System.EventArgs` to `System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs`

Answer (score 2):

The System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs.Empty is actually not an empty arg of type ElapsedEventArgs. By going to definition (F12), you will see, that it leads to the System.EventArgs.Empty.

As it is public, and ElapsedEventArgs inherits from EventArgs, it is also accessable via the ElapsedEventArgs class.