# Invoking elapsed Timer event in unit test failing due to ElapsedEventArgs not redeclaring Empty

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

The context is that I'm trying to unit test a System.Timers.Timer's elapsed event handler

I was following the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088455/1713336 which suggests invoking the event by creating a Timer wrapper and (note that this is FakeItEasy) using `timerFake.Elapsed += Raise.With<ElapsedEventArgs>(ElapsedEventArgs.Empty).Now;`

I've attempted doing so.

Unfortunately this results in a compiler error stating `Argument type 'System.EventArgs' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs'`

If you take a look [Nonsense error message when manually calling EventHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162084/nonsense-error-message-when-manually-calling-eventhandler) you'll be able to see that System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs doesn't redeclare Empty which I believe is why this error appears.

Is there a way around this? I still want to invoke the Elapsed timer event

Comment: From what I understand your suggestion does not work because it has a private constructor and cannot be instantiated

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31204

Comment: var ci = typeof(ElapsedEventArgs).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,  
                new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }, null);
            var obj = (ElapsedEventArgs)ci.Invoke(new object[] { 0, 0 });

Comment: Hi Hans can you explain what that code does?

Comment: It uses System.Reflection to bypass the limitation, standard technique in .net

Comment: Gotcha, I was hoping we could avoid reflection but it seems that's the only way

Comment: Ah let me clarify. I'm trying to raise the event in a unit test. That event is meant to trigger the Elapsed handler for my timer wrapper so I can assert some side effects that result from the handler being called.

The signature for that handler is `internal async void SomeHandler(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)`.


This is the documentation for `Raise.With` https://fakeiteasy.github.io/docs/7.3.1/raising-events/

Comment: Was able to find a solution! I raised it with a `timerFake.Elapsed += Raise.FreeForm.With(this, obj);` where `obj` is the ElapsedEventArgs created with reflection. Raise.FreeForm raises events defined with a custom delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a solution with some help from [@Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)

First we create an `ElapsedEventArgs` object with reflection

```
var ctor = typeof(ElapsedEventArgs).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).First();
var args = (ElapsedEventArgs)ctor.Invoke(new object[] {DateTime.Now});
```

Then I raised an event to trigger the timer's Elapsed handler with `timerFake.Elapsed += Raise.FreeForm.With(this, args)`; where `args` is the `ElapsedEventArgs` created with reflection.

`Raise.FreeForm` raises events defined with a custom delegate as documented here https://fakeiteasy.github.io/docs/7.3.1/raising-events/